# How can I use an animated gif that will play when pressed as a button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, animated-gif, kivy-language

I have this toggle button in kivy and I want it to animate on when pressed (it's a power on button gif) but without looping. I can't seem to find any useful information about this. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could show your code, you could also explain what the following phrase means: *but without looping*

Comment: I don't really see how any code would clarify the question, what i'm trying to learn is how to have a button animate from an off state to an on state when said button is pushed. To be more exact, here's a visual demonstration, [this](http://iceflowstudios.com/v3/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/GlowingPreview.gif) is very much like the gif i'd like to use.

Without looping meaning that the gif should only play once, after that it should be a still image of the powered on button

Comment: You can do this with a custom image instead of a Button because in a button the gifs are just like simple other images

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an instance of [`kivy.uix.image`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html) inside the button you can do:

- Disable animation at startup [`anim_delay = -1`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_delay).
- Specify the number of loops to be played using [`anim_loop = 1`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_loop)
- When the button is pressed, assign a positive value to `anim_delay` and restart animation using the [`anim_reset`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image.anim_reset) method of the `kivy.core.image` instance used by `kivy.uix.image` to contain the image.

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<ExampleApp>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: ""
        on_press: gif.anim_delay = 0.10
        on_press: gif._coreimage.anim_reset(True)

        Image:
            id: gif
            source: 'img.gif'
            center: self.parent.center
            size: 500, 500
            allow_stretch: True
            anim_delay: -1
            anim_loop: 1
""")

class ExampleApp(App, BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

---

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]